# Search for a string in a multi dimensional string array and get index of item

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have been trying to get the index of a string in an array and return the value of it with the Array.IndexOf Method, because other people told me that it worked, but I keep getting an error. Did I type my code wrong or something?

```
private string getBlockDataOrName(string nameOrData, string index)
{
    String[,] blocks = {{ "stone", "grass", "dirt", "trees", "logs", "shovel", "bedrock" },
                        { "6", "0", "2", "0", "5", "5", "0" }};

    if (nameOrData == "Data")
        return blocks[1, Array.IndexOf(blocks, index)];
    else
        return blocks[0, Convert.ToInt64(index)];

}
```

Here is the error that I keep getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.RankException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Only single dimension arrays are supported here.

I don't see how this will only work on a single dimensional array.

Comment: No there's not. I just ran it

Comment: I'm not talking about correctness, rather the practices and semantics behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a jagged array instead as follows:

```
private string getBlockDataOrName(string nameOrData, string index)
{
    String[][] blocks = {
                            new []{ "stone", "grass", "dirt", "trees", "logs", "shovel", "bedrock" },
                            new []{ "6", "0", "2", "0", "5", "5", "0" }
                        };

    if (nameOrData == "Data")
        return blocks[1][Array.IndexOf(blocks[1], index)];
    else
        return blocks[0][Convert.ToInt64(index)];

}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and saved me trouble with some other stuff as well

Answer (score 0):

> "I don't see how this will only work on a single dimensional array."

It's simply how the function `IndexOf` was designed, it returns an int, not multiple values, and isn't meant to support anything except single-dimension arrays